# PHPStorm 7 don't find PHP Interpreter on Windows

Tags: php, windows, interpreter, phpstorm

I have installed trial version of **PhpStorm 7** on my **Windows 7 64 bit**.
Php Storm is installed in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 7.0\bin\PhpStorm.exe"` and my Xampp server in in `E:\xampp.`
I go to set php interpreter but PhpStorm don't find it.
I opened phpinterpreter windows and choose directory `E:\xampp\php` but I receive more error like this

**Php Startup: Unable to load dynamic lybrary "\xampp\php\ext\php_xxxxxx.dll"......**

It seems that PhpStorm 7 trunks the path excluding the disc and cannot find the installation of php over xampp directory.

I forced write correct value in `C:\Users\currentuser\.WebIde70\config\options\php.xml` , but I have same result 
P

```
hp version: Not installed
Debugger: Not installed
```

but I have both installed and running.

What should I do to correct the problem?

Thanks very much

Comment: *"It seems that PhpStorm 7 trunks the path excluding the disc*" -- NO. This error comes from PHP itself -- check your `php.ini`. I personally see no PhpStorm fault here -- as far as I see it's problem with your PHP installation/configuration.

Comment: Here is how-to article: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Comment: I have xampp 1.8.2 with PHP 5.4.19 and all are running correctly. Any site under htdocs run very well. T

Comment: The only difference with article http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE is diferent hard disk installation for PhpStorm and Xampp. In the article are both in c:, in my configuration  PhpStorm is on C: and Xampp on E:

Comment: In such case I do not know what else I can suggest here -- this sort of error is common when PHP is not properly configured or cannot find some necessary .dll files. It's possible that when invoking validation routine (which is very simple -- parsing output of phpinfo();) from within IDE, PHP is unable to find some files due to difference in PATH environment or something. I personally never met this myself.

Comment: My only suggestion is to check `idea.log` file for possible details ... or install XAMPP on C: drive.

Comment: Here is one thing you may check -- create some .php file and put it on your website. The content is simple: `<?php phpinfo()` -- see what `Loaded Configuration File` says (the very first table). Now run `php -i` in console and see what the same field says there. It's possible that your installation has 2 separate php.ini files for Web and CLI environments.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me, however I'm in PhpStorm 8 and the layout is entirely different. I'll still pop this here in case someone else needs these instructions.

- Install your prefered PHP from here: http://windows.php.net/ *(It doesn't need to be in your PATH, just pop it anywhere)*
- In PhpStorm, go to File -> Settings
- In settings go to Languages & Frameworks -> PHP
- Click the ellipsis next to Interpretter (this opens a new window)
- Click the plus button in the top left and choose "Other Local"
- Set the PHP exectuable to wherever you put your download above. It just needs to see php.exe

That's it. I've been using that to run Composer from PhpStorm... though I'm not convinced by the results.

As an alternative I would *highly* recommend using Vagrant for your PHP needs. You don't need PHP in Windows at all, and I've been developing this way for about 2 years. PhpStorm's remote support (including Vagrant, SSH and Remote Interpreter) is now excellent. I think the only thing I've been irritated by is PHPUnit Code Coverage is still broken.

Comment: Is `php.exe` the proper executable I need to select? What do the others in the windows release (`php-win.exe`, `php-cgi` and `phpdbg.exe`) do?

Comment: Sorry for the year abd a bit delay on this, yes php.exe is the one to select. 